# Get row cell values as separate strings when clicking on row

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want to get the cells' values of a row in three separate string using datatables.

```
var table = $('#seats').DataTable();
            $('#seats').find('tr').click(function(){
                    var ta = table.row(this).data();
                    alert(ta);
```

I am able to get the row values as separated by comma. I am unable to use the split function as the datatables js doesn't recognize it. If I import jquery it breaks datatables. Thoughts?

I am currently getting this output.

> 352,NAME3,test+

I would like to separate the string into three different values and assign them to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ta** var is an array which contains all values :

> (3) ["352", "NAME3", "test+"]

It's the alert function which create a new string var and separated all your values by comma.

You can do a **for** on your ta in order to get all values separated :

```
$(document).on('click', '#seats tr', function(){
    var ta = table.row(this).data();
    for (var key in ta)
    {
        alert(ta[key]);
    }
});
```

Was it helpful?

Comment: Thanks that sort of worked. When I click on any row past the tenth, nothing happens.

Comment: Change your listener syntax, look at my example up above! This issue is caused by DataTable refreshing table html (on changing page result) ;)

Comment: I tried changing it to include the tr but nothing happens. No errors are given either.

Comment: Turns out it was a nesting problem.